# help configuring my samba file server

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, samba

Hello everyone I have installed all the files I needed for my samba file server. I have also installed the gadmin-samba 0.3.2. I am trying to set a user-name and password also I would like to know how to ad my laptops I own to the machines allowed to connect to it. it can be in terminal but preferably in gadmin-samba which is like a GUI. please be very descriptive my systems is Ubuntu 14.04 and Gadmin-Samba 0.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I can get you there with there from the commandline.  I don't use Gadmin.

First off, most of the default would probably work without making any changes.  All you should have to do is just add the folder specifications you want to share.

Pick a folder or create a folder called, for instance, "myshare".  Now edit and append these lines to the /etc/samba/smb.conf file:

```
[myshare]
        comment = My Shared Area
        path = /myshare
        writeable = yes
        browseable = yes
        valid users = user1, user2
```

The [myshare] is the name of the share that will appear on the network for connecting to the resource.  This doesn't have to match he actual folder name.  But having something similar to it will have you to remember the resource you have setup.

The valid users are the ones you have created to have access to the shares.  The user names will have to be a name that is actually on the Ubuntu machine.  You'll still have to add the names to Samba's access list.  You can do this with:

```
$ sudo smbpasswd -a user1
$ sudo smbpasswd -a user2
```

When the users are added you can always modify their passwords with:

$ sudo smbpasswd user1

After that is done you connect to the share with Windows the same way as you would any other windows shared folder.  The network resource would be:

For windows:

```
\\machine\myshare
```

For linux it would be:

```
//machine/myshare
```

A convenient way (semi GUI) is to bring up your file browser (either Windows or Linux) and type in the associated shared connection above into the address field of the file browser (windows' explorer or Ubuntu's natilus).

You can also connect to the Linux shared by typing this into a command terminal on Windows:

```
explorer \\machine\myshare
```

Comment: hello where do i click to find my original computer shared folder which will be my home folder

Comment: @user281745 You type the line I gave you into the file explorer and press enter.

Comment: when i type in 1(explorer \\machine\home) or 2(//machine/home) it give me 1(No command 'explorer' found did you mean: command 'jxplorer'(universe) explorer: command not found) 2(bash://machine/home: No such File or Directory

Comment: What version of Windows are you running that it can't find explorer?

Comment: I’m sorry I don’t use windows  when it said for Linux I was assuming it was for Ubuntu 14.04 and when I tried to change the spot in smb.config file and I as my users I created it says you don’t have the proper privileges to save this file

Comment: @user281745 There isn't a reference to smb.config in my answer.  There is a smb.conf file that would need the configuration I specified above.  You typed in the "explorer" command that will allow you to connect to the linux share from Windows.  Notice the wording.  You would use this command in a Linux command prompt:  `nautilus //machine/myshare`.  Keep in mind that you won't be able to access the share unless you set it up in the smb.conf file.  You can use "sudo" to edit the file.  If you get an error, add the [myshare] block to your question and post the error message to your question.

Comment: ok thank you i used the already their home file folder it says [homes] comment = Home Directories valid user = %U writeable = yes browseable = yes read only = no availiable = yes guest ok = no printable = no locking = no strict locking = no

Comment: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
 is what i got after entering your comman in the terminal

Comment: @user281745 If you're saying you can't run nautilus from the commandline, it might be that you don't have it properly installed.  What Fill manager are you running?

Comment: pcman fm is what im usingalso when i type in nautilus in ubuntu software center it comes up as installed do i need to priorities it like cancel one or unistall one

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide        btw i am ythe one who posted the question and i tried to use this but only my laptop is curently on my work group also btw i am using a wireless bridge on my lubuntu client

Comment: and also i have been trying to use samba program

Comment: @user281745 I can't immediately tell if you have performed the steps in the answer.  If you have, then you should be able to access the share by starting your file manager with the share as a parameter.  If you get an error we would have to take it from there.  So far you have been getting errors because apparently you are trying file managers that you don't have installed.  You don't have the Windows Explorer file manager in Linux, and you don't have the Nautilus file manager properly installed on your system.  If you have pcmanfm this should give you your share: `pcmanfm /machine/myshare`